# how does one update numbers inside mongoose model nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

can someone please explain what I am doing wrong. I am attempting to update a number value inside a nested array on my mongoose schema by adding two numbers

here is the section in question

```
  $set: {
    "shareHolders.$.shares": Number(req.existingStock) + Number(req.stock)
  }
```

req.existing shares is say 100 and req.stock is a formatted as a string but equals say 100 so, in short, the new value for the shares should be 200

BUT when i run the code the shares of the said shareholder does not change it remains the original value.

here is the full snippet

```
module.exports.updateShareHolder = function(req, callback) {

console.log('updateShareHolder');
console.log(req);
console.log(req.existingStock + Number(req.stock));

  Company.update({
      "_id": req.companyID,
      "shareHolders.userId": req.userID
    }, {
      $push: {
        "shareHolders.$.agreements": {
          agreementID: req.agreementID
        }
      }
    }, {
       $set: {
      "shareHolders.$.shares": Number(req.existingStock) + Number(req.stock)
  }
    }, function(err) {

          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, err);
          } else {
            console.log('updateShareHolder');
            callback(null, 'success');
          }


    })


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a number before doing your `update`.

```
    const updatedStock = Number(req.existingStock) + Number(req.stock)
```

then

```
     $set: {
      "shareHolders.$.shares": updatedStock
  }
```